# Customizing Video component to have border radius

Tags: html, css, video

Currently I'm trying to have make my video component look like this where there is a colored border and border radius:

[image]

I have tried adding border-radius="10px" in my `<video>` tag but it didn't show in the webpage. I have also tried having its parent class have a border-radius but there was still no change.

```
<div className="border">
         <video width="100%" height="100%" border-radius="10px" controls >
          <source src="PassportVid.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
         </video>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.border{
 border-radius="10px";
 border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

My result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like this.

```
video{
width:100%;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
border-radius:10px;
overflow:hidden;
border: 1px solid orange;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Now can you this type code:

```
**CSS:**
div{border-radius:20px;height: 300px; overflow: hidden;width: 300px;}
video{width: 100%; height: 100%;object-fit: cover;}

**HTML**
<div>
 <video width="320" height="240" controls src="movie.ogg" >
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```